# for each loop in oracle SQL With dynamic columns to display

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL please help me resolving the query as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ROG.GROUPID,
       CAPA1.PERC,
       CAPA1.TPTID
FROM AGREGATEDPOLICY APO
INNER JOIN REINSURANCEOPERATION RO ON APO.AGREGATEDPOLICYID = RO.AGREGATEDPOLICYID
INNER JOIN REINSURANCEOPERATIONGROUPINFO ROG ON RO.OPERATIONID = ROG.OPERATIONID
INNER JOIN (SELECT RIC.GROUPID GID, RIP.PERCENTAGE PERC, RIP.THIRDPARTYID TPTID
              FROM RI_REINSURANCECONTRACT RIC
        INNER JOIN RI_CONTRACTCOMPONENT RICC ON RICC.MAINID = RIC.RCID
        INNER JOIN RI_CCPARTICIPATION RICP ON RICP.CCID = RICC.CCID
        INNER JOIN RI_PARTICIPATION RIP ON RIP.PARTICIPATIONID = RICP.PARTICIPATIONID
        INNER JOIN RI_EXCESSLOSS RIE ON RIE.EXCESSLOSSID = RICC.CCID
        INNER JOIN EXCESOPERDIDA EXP ON EXP.PK = RIE.EXCESSDCOID
             WHERE RIC.REINSURANCECONTRACTTYPE = 0
               AND RICC.TYPE = 'LossExcess') CAPA1 ON ROG.GROUPID = CAPA1.GID
```

Now there might be more than one **THIRDPARTYID** for each **GROUPID**. I want to multiply 25 with the **PERCENTAGE** of every **THIRDPARTYID**.

For example if the output is

```
GROUPID PERCENTAGE THIRDPARTYID
2824    0.4        824603
2824    0.4        824500
2824    0.5        824603
2824    0.2        824601
2824    0.5        824500
```

I want to display the output as **RESULT1.....n** (Dynamically change the n depending on the THIRDPARTYID like below

```
GROUPID  RESULT1  RESULT2  RESULT3  RESULT4  RESULT5
2824     10       10       12.5     5        12.5
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add such calculation in select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ROG.GROUPID,
       CAPA1.PERC,
       CAPA1.TPTID,CAPA1.PERC*25 as RESULT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I had to edit the result output for the change in requirements, It would be a great help if you could suggest something

Comment: @AyubH it's a different question, can you ask a new question?

Comment: I have reached the Question limit, it is bit urgent can u suggest me something I can do